# How to correctly handle itemSize of UICollectionViewLayout on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a UICollectionViewSubclass with a custom UICOllectionViewLayout

How best do i handle the itemSize change on orientation change?

```
class CollectSubclass: UICollectionView {

    /// When orientation changes, then invalidate the layout
    open override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if ((traitCollection.verticalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection?.verticalSizeClass) || (traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection?.horizontalSizeClass)) {
            collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()   
        }
    }
}
```

Once the layout is invalidated on orientation change, 
I calculate the `size.width` of the cell, to the the `width` of the UICollectionView.

This works well of the iPhone 7 Plus simulator, but fails on the smaller simulators like iPhone 7, 5, SE etc.

It seems that once the `invalidateLayout` is called, the following function gets triggered

```
 /// Lays out subviews.
override open func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

This function in turn calls the `prepare` function on the `UICollectionViewLayout`subclass where I use new frame of the collectionView to calculate the cell's size.

On iPhone-7-Plus, `traitCollectionDidChange` is triggered once. And `layoutSubviews` is triggered once causing `prepare` to be triggered once.

On the smaller simulators, however, `traitCollectionDidChange` is triggered once, but `layoutSubviews` is triggered twice.

With the first trigger of `layoutSubviews`, the UICOllectionView frame size is *almost* what it should be. And on the second trigger, the UICOllectionView frame size is now the correct size it should be.

Being called twice with two different frame sizes will cause me to prepare the layout twice (which is very expensive).

Is there something that I missed from subclassing UICOllectionViews and UICollectionViewLayouts? Any help is appreciated.

**I can also provide the sample project if needed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in your setup, the width of one of your `UICollectionViewCells` is based solely on the size of the `UICollectionView` and the size and orientation of the screen (and no other factors), the following is a clean way to set the size of a collection view cell:

1) When the view first loads, precalculate what the size of a cell will be in portrait and in landscape.  Also create a variable `currCellDimensions` to hold the current dimensions of a cell, and set its initial value.

2) Override the function viewWillTransitionToSize along these lines:

```
    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    setCurrentCollectionCellDimensions(size)  // This code executes before the rotation begins, but "size" is the size that the main view is going to be after the rotation occurs. As of iOS 8, the size of an object swaps its width and its height when the UI changes its orientation.
    }
```

3) Implement setCurrentCollectionCellDimensions():

```
    func setCurrentCollectionCellDimensions(newSize: CGSize) {

    if (newSize.width < newSize.height) {
        // set currCellDimensions to what it should be in portrait orientation
    } else {
        // set currCellDimension to what it should be in landscape orientation
    }

    if collectionView != nil {

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() // To trigger sizeForItemAtIndexPath to recalculate cell sizes

    collectionView.reloadData() // To trigger cellForItemAtIndexPath to redraw the cells that are visible to the user.  Without this call, the cell layout looks wrong on some iPhones.
    }
}
```

4) Finally, have `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()` return `currCellDimensions`.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to use the function `viewWillTransitionToSize` because I am creating a UICOllectionView subclass, not a UIViewCOntroller subclass. I do not have access to the ViewController (except only as a weak delegate for the collectionView)

Comment: Is there any way to know the `viewWillTransitionToSize` without using a view controller?

Comment: No, but in whichever view controller will instantiate an instance of your `UICollectionView` subclass, you can implement `viewWillTransitionToSize()`.  Then in `viewWillTransitionToSize()` instead of calling `setCurrentCollectionCellDimensions(size)`, call `collectionView.setCurrentCollectionCellDimensions(size)`.Some of your logic has to come from the view controller and some of it will be part of your UICollectionView subclass, but they can communicate with each other.